# Printing PDF generated using makepdf in iPad Safari

Tags: ios, reactjs, ipad, safari, pdfmake

I am trying to show a dynamically generated pdf in an iFrame. It works fine in desktop browsers. In Safari iPad it is showing only the first page in the iFrame. Looks like URL.createObjectURL(blob) is getting only the first page. Below is the code. Appreciate your help.

```js
pdfMake.createPdf(dataInput).getBlob((blob) => {
   const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   const targetElement =
   document.querySelector("#iframeContainer");
   const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
   iframe.src = blobURL;
   iframe.id = "printIframe";
   targetElement?.appendChild(iframe);
   iframe.onload = function () {
       if (iframe && iframe.contentWindow) {
          iframe.contentWindow.print();
       }
    };
});
```